# Continuous function that is invertible in one argument---is its inverse continuous in both arguments?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, inverse

Suppose that $f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function and that it is invertible in its second argument, i.e. for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $f(x,\cdot)$ is invertible with inverse $f^{-1}(x,\cdot)$. Define $g(x,y) := f^{-1}(x,y)$. Is $g$ continuous as a function of $(x,y)$? Does the answer change if the assumptions are strengthened so that $f(x,\cdot)$ is strictly increasing (hence invertible) for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$?

I believe that for any given $x$, $g(x,\cdot)$ is continuous since $f(x,\cdot)$ is invertible on an open set (namely, $\mathbb{R}$). What I do not see is what would be required for continuity of $g(\cdot, y)$ for a given $y$, or for the stronger condition that $g$ is continuous in both arguments.

Comment: Is $f^{-1}$ a well defined thing? For each $x$ you have a function $g_x(\cdot) := f(x,\cdot)^{-1}$. Now, $f^{-1}(t)$ contains one point on each vertical line, namely $(x,g_x(t))$. In what sense do you want this to be continuous?

Comment: When you say " is invertible in the second argument,"  do you mean that for each x $f^{-1}(y)$ is invertible (where y is the second argument)?.  If so, it seems to me that you have generated a set of functions $f_x(y)$ each of which is continuous and invertible in y, and thus $f_x^{-1}$ is continuous in y since $f_x$ is. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in clarification. Closer to Feanor's terminology I am interested in when $g_{x}(y) := f^{-1}(x,y)$ is continuous as a two-argument function of $(x,y)$.